# How to make callback function in async/await style?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Currently I'm working with `jwt` in node.js app. I use `jwt.sign()` method which looks like this:

```
jwt.sign({
            accountID: user.accountID,
            email: user.email,

        }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, token) => {

            if (err) throw err
            res.json({token})
        })
```

I don't want to use callback. I want to transform this to `async/await`. As I know I have to return `new Promise` with `resole({})` and `reject(err)`. But I can't figure out how to use promise from sign() method. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: just wrap it all in a function and prepend "return await " to the code shown

Comment: [`require('util').promisify(jwt.sign)`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript (as well as libraries like Bluebird) has a built-in promisify function as `util.promisify()`, which will take functions with standard callback format like this and turn them into async promises. However, you can take the behind-the-scenes work and run it yourself, by wrapping the function you're trying to promisify in a new Promise call. Failing the utility, I'd do something like:

```
function sign(id, email, secret) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jwt.sign({ accountID: id, email: email }, secret, (error, token) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(token);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

You can then call it as:

```
const token = await sign(user.accountID, user.email, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
```

Comment: Node.js 8+ has [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

Comment: _So libraries like Bluebird have a method called `.promisify()`_ -- so does the Node.js builtin `util` module.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Been stuck in Node 6 land for awhile now. Glad to see they baked that functionality in!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the above code in node.js 8,you can use the promisify method. Check the proposal here: http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html

For other implementations consider using Bluebird promise library or any similar library. Bluebird promisify reference: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html